# Python Flet showing a dialog in class

Tags: python, flutter, user-interface, flet

I m writing a flet application. There is function main() and class App(). Page object is on main() and i'm using page.add(App()) to add Widgets to page.

In flet documentation there is a example usage

```
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "AlertDialog examples"

    dlg = ft.AlertDialog(
        title=ft.Text("Hello, you!"), on_dismiss=lambda e: print("Dialog dismissed!")
    )

    def close_dlg(e):
        dlg_modal.open = False
        page.update()

    dlg_modal = ft.AlertDialog(
        modal=True,
        title=ft.Text("Please confirm"),
        content=ft.Text("Do you really want to delete all those files?"),
        actions=[
            ft.TextButton("Yes", on_click=close_dlg),
            ft.TextButton("No", on_click=close_dlg),
        ],
        actions_alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.END,
        on_dismiss=lambda e: print("Modal dialog dismissed!"),
    )

    def open_dlg(e):
        page.dialog = dlg
        dlg.open = True
        page.update()

    def open_dlg_modal(e):
        page.dialog = dlg_modal
        dlg_modal.open = True
        page.update()

    page.add(
        ft.ElevatedButton("Open dialog", on_click=open_dlg),
        ft.ElevatedButton("Open modal dialog", on_click=open_dlg_modal),
    )

ft.app(target=main)
```

And this is my code:

```
import flet
from flet import Page, UserControl, Column, Container, colors, border_radius, padding, Text, Row, ElevatedButton, icons, \
    IconButton, Dropdown, dropdown, FontWeight, AlertDialog


def inf_on_click(page: Page):
    pass


class App(UserControl):
    def __init__(self, style):
        super().__init__()
        self.style = style

    def build(self):
        return Column(
            controls=[
                Container(
                    bgcolor=self.style["bg-color"],
                    width=450,
                    height=550,
                    border_radius=self.style["border-radius"],

                    content=(
                        Column(
                            alignment=flet.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                            horizontal_alignment=flet.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                            controls=[
                                Container(
                                    width=430,
                                    height=530,

                                    content=(
                                        Column(

                                            controls=[

                                                Row(

                                                    expand=True,
                                                    alignment=flet.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                                                    vertical_alignment=flet.CrossAxisAlignment.START,

                                                    controls=[
                                                        Column(
                                                            expand=True,
                                                            alignment=flet.MainAxisAlignment.START,
                                                            horizontal_alignment=flet.CrossAxisAlignment.START,
                                                            controls=[
                                                                IconButton(
                                                                    icon=icons.INFO,
                                                                    scale=0.8,

                                                                )
                                                            ]
                                                        ),
                                                        Column(
                                                            expand=True,
                                                            width=175,
                                                            alignment=flet.MainAxisAlignment.START,
                                                            horizontal_alignment=flet.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                                                            controls=[
                                                                Text("Hello!",
                                                                     size=25,

                                                                     )
                                                            ]

                                                        ),
                                                        Column(
                                                            expand=True
                                                        ),

                                                    ]
                                                ),
                                                Row(
                                                    expand=True,
                                                    alignment=flet.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                                                    controls=[
                                                        ElevatedButton(
                                                            text="Start Installation",
                                                            icon=icons.ARROW_RIGHT,
                                                            color=self.style["text-color"],
                                                            scale=1.2
                                                        )
                                                    ]
                                                ),
                                                Row(
                                                    expand=True,
                                                    alignment=flet.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                                                    vertical_alignment=flet.CrossAxisAlignment.START,
                                                    controls=[
                                                        Column(
                                                            expand=True,
                                                            alignment=flet.MainAxisAlignment.END,
                                                            horizontal_alignment=flet.CrossAxisAlignment.START,
                                                            controls=[
                                                                IconButton(
                                                                    icon=icons.POWER_SETTINGS_NEW,
                                                                    scale=1.3,
                                                                    tooltip="Shutdown",

                                                                )
                                                            ]
                                                        ),
                                                        Column(
                                                            width=175,

                                                            alignment=flet.MainAxisAlignment.END,
                                                            horizontal_alignment=flet.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                                                            controls=[
                                                                Dropdown(
                                                                    width=200,
                                                                    height=45,

                                                                    tooltip="Select Language",
                                                                    hint_text="Select Language",
                                                                    hint_style=flet.TextStyle(size=15),

                                                                    options=[
                                                                        dropdown.Option("English")
                                                                    ]
                                                                )

                                                            ]
                                                        ),
                                                        Column(expand=True,
                                                               alignment=flet.MainAxisAlignment.END,
                                                               horizontal_alignment=flet.CrossAxisAlignment.END,
                                                               controls=[
                                                                   IconButton(
                                                                       icon=icons.ARROW_RIGHT_ALT,
                                                                       tooltip="Use arch in archiso enviroment(Live CD)",
                                                                       scale=1.3
                                                                   )
                                                               ]
                                                               ),

                                                    ]
                                                )
                                            ]
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            ]
                        )

                    )

                )
            ]

        )


def main( page: Page):
   
    page.title = "EasyArch Utily"
    page.window_height = 600
    page.window_width = 500
   

    style = {
        "text-color": colors.WHITE,
        "secondary-bg-color": colors.WHITE60,
        "bg-color": colors.BLACK12,
        "border-radius": 8
    }
    app = App(style)
    page.add(app)
    page.vertical_alignment = "center"
    page.horizontal_alignment = "center"

    page.update()


flet.app(main)
```

This is okey but i'm wanting show a dialog from App() class. How can i do this?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample:

```py
import flet
from flet import Page, UserControl, Column, Container, colors, border_radius, padding, Text, Row, ElevatedButton, icons, \
    IconButton, Dropdown, dropdown, FontWeight, AlertDialog, MainAxisAlignment


def inf_on_click(page: Page):
    pass


class App(UserControl):
    def __init__(self, style):
        super().__init__()
        self.style = style

    def show_dlg(self, e):
        dlg_modal = AlertDialog(
            modal=True,
            title=Text("Please confirm"),
            content=Text("Do you really want to delete all those files?"),
            actions=[
                ElevatedButton("Yes", on_click=lambda x: x.page.close_dialog()),
                ElevatedButton("No", on_click=lambda x: x.page.close_dialog()),
            ],
            actions_alignment=MainAxisAlignment.END,
            on_dismiss=lambda x: print("Modal dialog dismissed!"),
        )

        # e.page gives direct us access to the page and all its methods
        e.page.show_dialog(dlg_modal)


    def build(self):
        return Column(
            controls=[
                ElevatedButton("Show Alert Dialog", on_click=self.show_dlg)
            ]
        )

def main(page: Page):
    page.title = "EasyArch Utily"
    page.window_height = 600
    page.window_width = 500

    style = {
        "text-color": colors.WHITE,
        "secondary-bg-color": colors.WHITE60,
        "bg-color": colors.BLACK12,
        "border-radius": 8
    }
    app = App(style)
    page.add(app)
    page.vertical_alignment = "center"
    page.horizontal_alignment = "center"

    page.update()


flet.app(main)
```